# Difficulty maintaining a tree structure with Riverpod (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, tree, nodes, riverpod

I've been learning Flutter recently for one of my personal projects. For the project, I need to implement a file system within the app in which each folder acts as a Node with optional child Nodes. The app also needs to keep track of the current folder that is open so the user can navigate between the different directories. For that, I have been using Riverpod's StateNotifier. But for reasons I'm unsure of, the state of the entire tree doesn't seem to be fully maintained when the current Node is updated. I've set up a ProviderObserver to help me debug, and the resulting logs seem to suggest that there are no issue with adding child Nodes to the root Node. The issue only arises when I update the current notifier state to a child Node. When that happens, the root Node suddenly loses many of its child Nodes, including the Node I am currently accessing. Even when I return to the root Node, many of the child Nodes seem to be missing. Is there something I've overlooked in the code or is there something else going on? I would appreciate any sort of help or advice. Thanks.

```
class Node {
  Node? parentNode;
  final String id;
  final String value;
  final List<Node> childNodes;

  Node({
    this.parentNode,
    required this.id,
    required this.value,
    this.childNodes = const [],
  });

  void addNode(Node node) {
    childNodes.add(node);
  }

  List<Node> getAllNodes() {
    return childNodes;
  }

  Node copyWith({
    Node? parentNode,
    String? id,
    String? value,
    List<Node>? childNodes,
  }) {
    return Node(
      parentNode: parentNode ?? this.parentNode,
      id: id ?? this.id,
      value: value ?? this.value,
      childNodes: childNodes ?? this.childNodes,
    );
  }
}
```

```
class CurrentNodeNotifier extends StateNotifier<Node> {
  CurrentNodeNotifier()
      : super(
          Node(
            parentNode: null,
            id: uuid.v4(),
            value: 'ROOT',
          ),
        );

  void addNode(String value) {
    final newNode = Node(
      parentNode: state,
      id: uuid.v4(),
      value: value,
    );
    state = state.copyWith(childNodes: [...state.childNodes, newNode]);
  }

  void changeCurrentNode(Node newNode) {
    state = newNode;
  }

  void returnToParent() {
    if (state.parentNode != null) {
      state = state.parentNode!;
    }
  }
}

final currentNodeProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<CurrentNodeNotifier, Node>((ref) {
  return CurrentNodeNotifier();
});
```

Comment: I never ended up solving this issue. Instead, I decided to use a roundabout method of using a normalized tree structure and using an additional state provider to return the id of the current node I am on. This method should be more foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

There is a strong suspicion that this is due to the lack of immutability of your `Node` model. Note the field `Node? parentNode;`. See if using `final` solves the problem for `parentNode` field.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. After further debugging, I noticed that the child Nodes were not disappearing at random. It seems that when I call the addNode function in the Provider, the Node being passed into the parent Node is not actually a reference to the initial root Node but instead an older instance of it. As such, when I do the following steps:

1. Add Node A to the root Node

2. Add Node B to the root Node

3. Access Node B and B's parent Node only contains Node A

4. Access Node A and A's parent Node doesn't contain any child Node